# How to trace errors logs of the Stored Procedure in PROD environment?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g, websphere-7

I am not an expertise in oracle DB. But I am curious to know that how can we check the logs of particular Stored procedure when it gets executed.

I check the trace folder but I dont know how and which file I have to analyse.

When I checked the UNIX logs it shows timeout error . It seems it did not get the response form one of the procedure. And after 2-3 hrs it get processed and sometimes it dosent. It should have done that job in 30 mnts max. I am not sure if DB is culprit or WEB SERVER (WAS) .

In extreme case I ask for DB restart and WAS restart and this solves our problem .

Is it possible to trace the problem? I am in PROD environment . The same is not behavior in UAT or in SIT environment 
Could this be the problem from WAS or DB side? Please throw some light on this .

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is [DBMS_TRACE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_trace.htm#CACEIHAH) You'll have to enable tracing in your session and execute the procedure manually.

If by chance, this procedure is being executed by ORACLE scheduler you may find some info in alert log. I'd suggest checking that anyway.

If the procedure used to run in 30min and now takes 2h to complete and if there were no changes to it then the problem is not in the procedure.

I'd suggest you check for unusable indexes, redo log switches, blocking sessions, table locks etc. hard to say exactly without knowing the procedure. You say it's a prod environment. DBA must surely have some performance monitoring in place. If, by chance, you have Oracle Enterprise Manager go and take a look at what is happening while the procedure is being executed.

Comment: Thank you for the reply . I will check the above said method tomorrow and will update !
The problem dosent replicate in any other environment  UAT nor in SIT and worst that no dedicated DBA .

Comment: Also, I have changed the question in some extend .Pls see if you can suggest me anything

Comment: Well if it doesn't replicate on SIT and UAT that really doesn't mean anything. These environments usually contain less data than PROD. Also unusable index wouldn't show problems on other environment. I see that you've added WAS. Well if was is giving you timeout, then it'll definitely show in WAS logs. I don't think WAS would cause 1,5h delay in execution it looks like DB issue to me. That is more common.

Comment: Could you check SELECT * FROM DBA_INDEXES (or ALL_INDEXES under user which executes the procedure) and cross-reference with tables that are used by the procedure in question. Also please check alert log and make sure there not problems listed there.

Comment: Is it safe to use  DBMS_TRACE  in PROD ?

Comment: If you want to use DBMS_TRACE you need to create special tables where the output data will be stored. This may be against your policy on PROD. Otherwise you can limit the amount of data that is logged with TRACE_LIMIT and TRACE_LEVEL Script to create these tables is in $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/tracetab.sql